# How to bind a forwarded local port to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1? "Operation not permitted" when using GatewayPorts=yes

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, ipv4

A (remote) SSH server `remote` runs a service on (remote) 127.0.0.1 port 20001. I want to make this service available locally via SSH port forwarding:

```
ssh -vvv -4 -L 20001:127.0.0.1:20001 remote
```

Port forwarding and accessing the service works fine with this command.

However, the tunnel binds to 127.0.0.1 on my local machine, so the remote service is only reachable on my local machine which runs the SSH command. I want the tunnel to bind to 0.0.0.0, so the remote service is available in my local LAN, by connecting to my local machine port 20001.

The manpage for the `-L` option mentions:

> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts setting. However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the connection to a specific address. The bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates that the port should be available from all interfaces.

Source: https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html#L

So I added the `GatewayPorts=yes` setting and tried both

```
ssh -vvv -4 -o GatewayPorts=yes -L 20001:127.0.0.1:20001 remote
```

as well as

```
ssh -vvv -4 -o GatewayPorts=yes -L *:20001:127.0.0.1:20001 remote
```

but I get the following error:

> ```
> debug1: Local connections to *:20001 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:20001
> debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 1 addr NULL
> debug1: Local forwarding listening on 0.0.0.0 port 20001.
> listen: Operation not permitted
> listen [0.0.0.0]:20001: Operation not permitted
> channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 20001
> Could not request local forwarding.
> ```

How do I bind the forwarded local port to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1? Where does the error come from?

- When binding to 127.0.0.1, the port is available. Nevertheless, I double-checked with `netstat` that the port is not in use.
- It doesn't help running the SSH command with `sudo`.
- I assume that it's only necessary to set `GatewayPorts=yes` in `sshd_config` on the server when you want to use remote port forwarding with binding 0.0.0.0 on remote side. I changed the server config anyway, restarted the server, which had, as expected, no effect on my SSH command for local port forwarding.

Comment: Anything special about your environment? Container, running Tor (ie: a library wrapper)? Asking this because the man page for `listen(2)` doesn't even show EPERM as a possible error (on Linux. As you're linking a Debian man page for ssh, I assume you're using Debian or a standard Linux).

Comment: is `ufw` enabled? I.e. `sudo ufw status`?